# The sprinkles aren't spread out on the icing - why? (Answered)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been following Blender Guru's new Blender 3.0 tutorial, and at the sprinkles chapter I noticed that my node setup is more or less the same as Andrew's, yet I only see one cylinder and it's not even on my donut icing.

Could someone please tell me where I'm wrong? Why aren't the sprinkles spread out on the doughnut icing?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you've picked an object to instance in the *Object Info* node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable *as instance* in the Object Info node; and you need to select an object to instance. I would guess "Cylinder" from your outliner:

[image: Object Info showing selection and 'as instance' enabled]

Where I have "sprinkle.001" you need the name of your sprinkle.

Tip:  It's always a good idea to name objects.  Makes it easy to see what you're doing.